# I'm trying to get Textarea value from a dynamically generated form but when I click the button nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML document completely generated from jQuery, and in that I have a form. I am trying to get the value entered inside the text area when I click on the button but it stays 'undefined'.

My HTML in jQuery:

```
jQuery('<form/>', {
    id: 'username_form',
    "class": 'username_form'
    }).appendTo('#header');

    jQuery('<h2/>', {
    text: 'Please enter a Username',
    id: 'popuptitle',
    "class": 'username_title'
    }).appendTo('#username_form');

    jQuery('<textarea rows="1" col"50"/>', {
    id: 'username_text',
    "class": 'username_form'
    }).appendTo('#username_form');
    /*      btn submit   */ 
    var btn_submit= document.createElement('input');
    btn_submit.setAttribute('id','btn_Submit');
    btn_submit.setAttribute('type','button');
    btn_submit.setAttribute('name','btn_Submit');
    btn_submit.setAttribute('value','Submit');
    $(btn_submit).appendTo('#username_form');
```

My function:

```
    $('#btn_Submit').click(function() {
        //alert("Submitted");
        var username = $.trim($("#username_text").val());
        alert($("textarea#username_text").text());

        if(username != ""){
                // Show alert dialog if value is not blank
                alert(username);
            }
    });
```

The only thing happening in my alert is a blank or 'undefined'

Comment: You have to use delegated event, use `$(document).on("click",'#btn_Submit',function() {`

Comment: instead of the `code $('#btn_Submit').click(function() ` ?

Comment: Why not alert the username variable, instead of switching from val() to text()? You're not actually testing your variable's definition here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem related to jQuery's function **jQuery** when you try to create a textarea. It doesn't get the informed **id**. If you use only this way:

```
jQuery('<textarea/>', {
```

It works. (but you also need to use **.val()** instead of **.text()**.

Comment: Its the row/col messing it up, wow i did not know that, thank you!

Comment: actually even with the `col="50"` it doesnt work but if i remove both it does

Comment: Oh, so I rolled back the previous answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create dynamic element, jQuery don't know about this element at starting time and cannot attach event to it. You button element cannot bind event.

You have to bind your event to existing parent element like so:

```js
$(document).on("click",'#btn_Submit',function() {
...
});
```

Comment: The problem isnt the 'click' that works perfectly, its trying to get whats inside of the textarea after somebody typed into it

Comment: Use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: tried both `.val()` returns 'undefined' and `.text()` just returns a blank space It never actually get what is written in the textarea